# create dynamic variable names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a very simple example of creating a variable in Python:

```
model_result = 5
```

Now the problem is that, I need to run a same snippet of codes for a lot of model scenarios, and save out the final result from each scenario with a corresponding name.

When using this snippet of codes, I will only update the chosen scenario using a hashtag (#), and keep the remaining analysis codes untouched. For example:

```
# pick a scenario
chosen_scenario = "baseline"
#chosen_scenario = "test1"
#chosen_scenario = "test2"
#chosen_scenario = "test3"
#chosen_scenario = "test4"
#chosen_scenario = "test5"
print("Chosen scenario:",chosen_scenario)

# move to the corresponding directory and get the files
Target_files = sorted(glob.glob("C:/model-outputs/"+chosen_scenario+"_output/model_output_*.csv"))

# Then run through some fixed routine analysis
```

At the end of the snippet, I want to save out the variable direclty as something like:
`model_result_baseline`,`model_result_test1`,`model_result_test2`, instead of manually typing them every time. Because there are a lot of scenarios.

Is this possible in Python?

Many thanks.

Comment: you mean something like `f"model_result_{chosen_scenario}"`?

Comment: @matszwecja Yes, but ```f"model_result_{chosen_scenario}" = 5``` does not work. As a value can not be assigned to a string.

Comment: If that is what you want to do, you should use a dictionary: `model_result = {}; model_result[chosen_scenario] = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by adding variables dynamically to global/local dictionary using `globals()` or `locals()` or `vars()`

```py
for chosen_scenario in scenarios:
    path = "C:/model-outputs/" + chosen_scenario + "_output/model_output_*.csv"
    globals()[chosen_scenario] = sorted(glob.glob(path))
```

Check [my post](https://higee.io/create-variables-dynamically-feat-globals-locals-vars-dcb48cbf399d) for some more details.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a dictionary to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
results = {}
scenarios = ['baseline', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']
for s in scenarios:
    results[s] = sorted(glob.glob(f"C:/model-outputs/{s}_output/model_output_*.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You question needs clarification but is below what you ask for ?

Put scenarios in list

```
scenarios = ["baseline", "test1"]
```

then run your script in for loop;

```
for scenario in scenarios:
    Target_files = sorted(glob.glob("C:/model-outputs/" + scenario + "_output/model_output_*.csv"))
```

Also when you put them in list instead using hashtag to comment out other scenarios you can access the scenario you want by using list index;

```
scenarios[index]
```